# (soft question) why do we study complex measures and complex-valued functionals in modern analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

Recently I am struggling with "complex" things for my "real" analysis class. We are using Folland's Real analysis, 2nd for text book. It seems that Folland is trying to use complex-valued functions and linear functionals and complex measures whenever it is possible.

I have seen several examples in the probability theory using dominated convergence theorem for complex-valued functions to verify the limit of characteristic functions. But why is it so important for us to develop complex functionals and complex measures? Could anybody show me a few examples in which real functionals and real measures cannot serve the purpose?

Comment: I think the ultimate reason is that analysis isn't so nice on $\Bbb R$ because it isn't algebraically closed. Since you need the complex numbers eventually, it's best to start with it from the get-go. One of the things you find is that in a Banach algebra, the spectrum (think eigenvalues) of an operator $A$ is the same as the image set of the *multiplicative* linear functionals evaluated at $A$. The spectrum of an operator is something we are acutely interested in and is, in general, complex-valued. If we only had real functionals, we'd be unable to make that association.

Comment: In addition, the spectrum of an operator over $\mathbb{R}$ may be empty, but over $\mathbb{C}$ it is always non-empty. This is a very useful fact in functional analysis.